# What are some good alternatives to Whisper for blockchain messaging?

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper, message

I have been experimenting with Ethereum and I achieved good results with Whisper in a private network. The main problem though is that it is pretty slow even when nodes are running in the same computer because messages take between 300-800ms to be received. What are some faster alternatives? My requirements are to be able to send small JSON messages as fast as possible.

Answer (score 3):

### Whisper

First of all, Whisper is kind of a database to spread announcements to the Ethereum network - or more precisely, to all `geth` nodes who have enabled Whisper. By default, Whisper is hidden behind a flag.

Whisper *can* be used to send messages. Sending messages will have the following properties:

- Receiver anonymity: no one knows who the actual receiver is
- **No** sender anonymity: a global passive adversary (e. g. your network service provider) can see the origin of the message
- **Uncertainty** whether a message reached its destination. You can increase the probability by using a higher TTL value but this comes with the drawback that you need to equip the message with a significantly more difficult proof of work.

The problem of Whisper is that each message is flooded through the network until its TTL is reached - even if it has reached the desired destination. And to prevent people from spamming the the network, Whisper nodes only accept messages with a certain proof-of-work which is closely related to the TTL value.

In private networks, this is not a problem. But the bigger the network becomes, the worse it gets.

### Anonymous / Privacy preserving communication

There's the [*anonymity trilemma*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/954.pdf) which states that you can achieve only two out of the following properties:

- **Strong anonymity**
- **Low latency**
- **High throughput**

So when, you want to send "messages as fast as possible" you need to live without strong anonymity.

### Alternatives

At the moment, there something like a *Whisper 2.0* for point-to-point messaging under development. The project is called [`hopr`](https://github.com/validitylabs/messagingProtocol). Its goal is to have:

- provable anonymity / privacy preserving communication as it uses the [SPHINX packet format](https://cypherpunks.ca/~iang/pubs/Sphinx_Oakland09.pdf)
- incentivations for the parties / nodes that relay messages
- adaptable anonymity - the user can choose to some extend the degree of privacy / anonymity by sacrificing

  - latency or
  - low relay fees or
  - privacy guarantees

A [working group](https://github.com/w3f/messaging) has been formed, including [Status.im](https://status.im), [Validity Labs](https://validitylabs.org) and [Web3 Foundation](https://web3.foundation).

Answer (score 0):

[PSS (Postal Service over Swarm)](https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pss.html) has no benchmarks, but it sends a message only to a registered node, so I assume it to be faster.

Disclaimer: I work with the Swarm team.

Comment: That's interesting. Is there any fee to use PSS?

Comment: Not at the moment. We're working on introducing an incentivisation model.